# Why have I been getting "Build failed" message while trying to deploy app to Render?

Tags: python, server-side-rendering, streamlit

I have been trying to deploy an app to render, but I keep getting the above message.

I used `pipreqs --encoding=utf8` to automatically generate the requirements files for the app which contains the following:

```
Pillow==9.3.0
Pillow==9.2.0
Pillow==10.0.0
Requests==2.31.0
streamlit==1.11.0
streamlit==1.25.0
streamlit_lottie==0.0.5
```

I went on to create a `Github` repository and uploaded the files for the app to the repository. I then connected the repository to render's `Webservice` option. The render's build failed message is as follows:

```
Aug 12 06:49:53 PM  ==> Cloning from https://github.com/TyRonmi/brookfield-website...
Aug 12 06:49:54 PM  ==> Checking out commit 043a238d41e018f7eb6f168203d2dccd4bd9f9fc in branch master
Aug 12 06:49:58 PM  ==> Using Node version 14.17.0 (default)
Aug 12 06:49:58 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
Aug 12 06:49:58 PM  ==> Using Python version 3.7.10 (default)
Aug 12 06:49:58 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a Python version: https://render.com/docs/python-version
Aug 12 06:50:02 PM  ==> Using Poetry version 1.1.14 (default)
Aug 12 06:50:02 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a Poetry version: https://render.com/docs/poetry-version
Aug 12 06:50:02 PM  ==> Running build command 'pip install -r requirements.txt'...
Aug 12 06:50:03 PM  ERROR: Double requirement given: Pillow==9.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (already in Pillow==9.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)), name='Pillow')
Aug 12 06:50:03 PM  WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 23.2.1 is available.
Aug 12 06:50:03 PM  You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/render/project/src/.venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Aug 12 06:50:03 PM  ==> Build failed
```

Please, how do I resolve this?

I tried to delete earlier versions of the duplicated modules in the `requirements.txt` file with no success.

Comment: What happened when you removed the duplicate lines? "with no success" probably means some other error happened, and that's probably what you should be investigating. You do have to remove those duplicate lines, that much is clear, since you have to install 9.2.0, or 9.3.0, but you can't simultaneously have both in the same environment.

Comment: 'Aug 13 02:12:17 PM  ERROR: No matching distribution found for Pillow==10.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Aug 13 02:12:17 PM  WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 23.2.1 is available.
Aug 13 02:12:17 PM  You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/render/project/src/.venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Aug 13 02:12:17 PM  ==> Build failed '

That is the error message i got after deleting earlier versions of duplicate libraries from 'requirements.txt' file

Comment: What version of Python are you using? https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ says Pillow 10.0.0 requires Python >= 3.8, so make sure your Python is at least that recent if you want to use 10.0.0, or use an older version of Pillow if you need to use an older Python. You should also upgrade pip, as the message suggests.